# cannot use the n1 in a simple recursive prolog program. Keep getting Undefined procedure: n/1

Tags: recursion, prolog, formatting

```
writeList([]).
writeList([H|T]) :-
   write(H),
   n1,
   writeList(T).
```

gives

```
?- 
% c:/users/mckie/onedrive/desktop/ex7 compiled 0.00 sec, 0 clauses
?- writeList([car, van, lorry]).
car
ERROR: Undefined procedure: n/1
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] n(1)
ERROR:    [8] writeList([car, van, lorry]) at c:/users/mckie/onedrive/desktop/ex7.pl:2
ERROR:    [7] <user>
   Exception: (9) n(1) ?
```

correct output should be:

```
car
van
lorry
```

Answer (score 1):

In

```
writeList([]).
writeList([H|T]) :-
   write(H),
   n1,
   writeList(T).
```

It is not `n1` with a number one (1), it should be `nl` with the letter `N` followed by the letter `L`, both in lower case, which is short for new line. See [nl/0](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nl/0)